# Google Storage PHP client: Can't create object by POSTing to signed URL

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

We're using the [Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageObject](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Storage/src/StorageObject.php)'s signedUploadUrl method in the backend to generate upload URLs for our JS-based clients to be able to upload data into these URLs without need of authentication.

This URL is then retrieved by the clients, which in turn [start a resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) by creating a storage object with a POST request in order to obtain an upload_id, and subsequent PUT requests would add data to it making use of this upload_id as authenticating factor.

Problem we're facing is that this signed upload URL is not behaving as expected: we're supposed to POST metadata (file name, content type) to it in order to obtain an upload_id, but this request fails with "SignatureDoesNotMatch".

As we're using the official PHP client library, we're clueless on what can be happening for this to be not working.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to send content-type header together with your subsequent PUT requests ?
Since generated signed upload URL is being created together with content-type header, subsequent PUT requests must send the same header.

Have a look at here: [google-cloud-php](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.90.0/storage%2Fstorageobject?method=signedUploadUrl)

options->contentType: If you provide this value, the client must provide this HTTP header set to the same value.